# Comparing two binary search tree

Tags: c, windows, recursion, gcc, binary-search-tree

What I'm trying to do is compare two binary search trees. This is in order to count the number of repetition that occurs on them.

First, I added this function that finds a specific element in a binary search tree.

```
node *search(node **tree, char val)
{
    if (!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if (val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if (val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}
```

And then I was thinking about going over one of the trees and comparing with each element but it doesn't work.

```
int countRepetition(node *tree, node *secondTree)
{
    node *tempCount;
    tempCount = search(&secondTree, tree->data);
    if (tempCount->data < tree->data)
    {
        countRepetition(tree->left, tempCount);
    }
    else if (tempCount->data > tree->data)
    {
        countRepetition(tree->right, tempCount);
    }
    else if (tempCount->data == tree->data)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect is for example: if the first tree has a, b, c, d on it and the second has a, d, m, k on it then the function should return 2. I would be so nice if someone help me, I'm dying because I'm new to C language.

This is the whole code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct bin_tree
{
    char data;
    struct bin_tree *right, *left;
} node;
void insert(node **tree, char val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if (!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if (val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    } 
    else if (val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }
}
node *search(node **tree, char val)
{
    if (!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if (val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if (val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}

int countRepetition(node *tree, node *secondTree)
{
    node *tempCount;
    tempCount = search(&secondTree, tree->data);
    if (tempCount->data < tree->data)
    {
        countRepetition(tree->left, tempCount);
    }
    else if (tempCount->data > tree->data)
    {
        countRepetition(tree->right, tempCount);
    }
    else if (tempCount->data == tree->data)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char main(char argc, char const *argv[])
{
    node *root, *secondRoot;
    node *tmp;

    root = NULL;
    /*Here i create the first tree*/
    insert(&root, 'a');
    insert(&root, 'b');
    insert(&root, 'c');
    insert(&root, 'd');
    insert(&root, 'j');
    insert(&root, 'k');
    insert(&root, 'z');
    //Here i create the second tree
    insert(&secondRoot, 'p');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'b');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'f');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'd');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'g');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'k');
    insert(&secondRoot, 'h');

    printf("\n%d\n", countRepetition(root, secondRoot));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm baffled. Normally binary search trees don't have repetition.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: well i'm expecting the number of repetition, for example if the first tree has the letters  a,b,c and the second tree has a,m,c then it should return 2 because the first and the second tree have the letter a and c

Comment: need a complete program in order to debug

Comment: Let me add the whole code at the end of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the issues:

- The declaration of `main` is wrong. It should be:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  ```
- `secondRoot` is not initialised. It should be initialised to `NULL`
- `search` does not return a value after having made a recursive call. It should `return` that recursive call's result.
- `search` should not need a pointer-pointer argument. Since it does not alter the tree, let be its root, it only needs a single-pointer argument.
- `countRepetition` should check whether `tempCount` is NULL, to avoid undefined behaviour with `tempCount->data`.
- Given that `search` either returns a node with the searched value *or* NULL, the tests `tempCount->data > tree->data` and `tempCount->data < tree->data` don't make sense. These should never be true.
- The only `return` statements in `countRepetition` return 0 or 1, so there is no way this function would return another integer value.
- It looks like you wanted to implement some binary search, but this means that even if the above points would be corrected, you would never visit all nodes in the first tree, so you would very likely miss some matching values.

#### Time Complexity

It seems your idea was to visit every value in the first tree, and for each perform a search in the second tree, and then count the matches. If we call  the number of nodes in the first tree, and  the number of nodes in the second tree, then this represents a time complexity of O(log).

For small trees, this is fine, but if  and  are both large, we can do better. We could iterate the values in the first tree in sorted order (i.e. in inorder traversal), and do this for the second tree as well, *at the same* time. We would go to the next node in one of the two traversals when it is the lesser of the two currently visited nodes. This way we walk through both trees in "tandem". As the visit is in order of value, we will be sure to find equal values this way.

This alternative algorithm represents a time complexity of O(+). When  and  have the same order of magnitude, this is a better time complexity than the first algorithm offers.

#### Implementation

I would suggest creating a kind of iterator for visiting nodes in inorder sequence, so that you can at any time ask for the successor of a node in that traversal. For this you'd need a stack (e.g. linked list), so to know which are the ancestors of the current node that still need to be visited.

Here is the code that would need to be added for that aspect:

```
// Stack implementation
typedef struct node_list
{
    struct bin_tree *node;
    struct node_list *next;
} nodeList;

void pushFront(nodeList **head, node *newNode) {
    nodeList *newHead = malloc(sizeof(nodeList));
    newHead->node = newNode;
    newHead->next = *head;
    *head = newHead;
}

node *popFront(nodeList **head) {
    nodeList *front = *head;
    node *frontNode = front->node;
    *head = front->next;
    free(front);
    return frontNode;
}

// Inorder tree iterator implementation
nodeList *treeIterator(node *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return NULL;
    nodeList *head = NULL;
    pushFront(&head, root);
    // Push path to left-most node (which has least value)
    while (root->left != NULL) {
        root = root->left;
        pushFront(&head, root);
    }
    return head;
}

node *next(nodeList **head) {
    if (*head == NULL) return NULL;
    node *currentNode = popFront(head);
    node *nextNode = currentNode;
    if (nextNode->right != NULL) {
        nextNode = nextNode->right;
        pushFront(head, nextNode);
        while (nextNode->left != NULL) {
            nextNode = nextNode->left;
            pushFront(head, nextNode);
        }
    }
    return currentNode;
}
```

The actual algorithm can then be implemented as follows:

```
int countRepetition(node *tree, node *secondTree)
{
    int count = 0;
    
    nodeList *iterator1 = treeIterator(tree);
    nodeList *iterator2 = treeIterator(secondTree);

    node *node1 = next(&iterator1);
    node *node2 = next(&iterator2);
    while (node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL) {
        if (node1->data < node2->data) {
            node1 = next(&iterator1);
        } else if (node1->data > node2->data) {
            node2 = next(&iterator2);
        } else {
            count++;
            node1 = next(&iterator1);
            node2 = next(&iterator2);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is the fix for the `search` function (see above comments):

```
node *search(node *tree, char val)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (val < tree->data)
    {
        return search(tree->left, val);
    }
    else if (val > tree->data)
    {
        return search(tree->right, val);
    }
    else if (val == tree->data)
    {
        return tree;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to initialise `secondTree = NULL` in `main`, and to free the memory used by your trees (I'll leave that for you to take care of).

Answer (score 0):

Some major errors here

first your code does not initialize root and secondRoot here

```
 node *root, *secondRoot;
```

should be

```
    node* root = NULL, * secondRoot = NULL;
```

next this line

```
 tempCount = search(&secondTree, tree->data);
```

does not check to see if NULL was returned , so the next line

```
 if (tempCount->data < tree->data)
```

fails in that case.

Note the double pointer passing is not needed and makes you code very hard to read. You only need it on insert where you actually allocate the root node. All other calls do not change the passed in tree pointer. I would have a 'createTree' function that returns an empty tree, and then insert does not need that special case code

but mainly - learn to use your debugger.

Comment: Also, not all code paths return a value, and the countRepetition function only ever returns 0 or 1.